# Local iOS Notifications - Launching a Terminated App in the Background

Tags: ios, background, notifications, unusernotificationcenter

I am reading the iOS documentation for [Scheduling and Handling Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1). I am stuck on a point in the section below.

> Responding to the Selection of a Custom Action
>
> When the user selects a custom action from the notification interface,
>   the system notifies your app of the user’s choice. Responses to custom
>   actions are packaged in a UNNotificationResponse object and delivered
>   to the delegate of your app’s shared UNUserNotificationCenter object.
>   To receive responses, your delegate object must implement the
>   userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:
>   method. Your implementation of that method must be able to process all
>   of the custom actions supported by your app or app extension.
>
> If your app or app extension is not running when a response is
>   received, the system launches your app or app extension in the
>   background to process the response. Use the provided background time
>   to update your data structures and your app’s interface to reflect the
>   user’s choice. Do not use the time to perform tasks unrelated to the
>   processing of the custom action.

specifically:

> If your app or app extension is not running when a response is
>   received, the system launches your app or app extension in the
>   background to process the response.

Does this mean that if a user responds to a local notification by tapping a custom action, and the app is closed (completely terminated), that the app will not be launched into the foreground? I have understood "launching an app in the background" to mean that the app would remain in the background to perform specific tasks there.

And, if the app is not launched into the foreground, why would we need to update the UI?

I am surely missing something here.